# Reading a multiple key-value file

Tags: r, file, text

Is there a way to read following type of text file in R

```
Key1=Value11|Key2=Value21|Key3=Value31|...
Key1=Value12|Key2=Value22|Key3=Value32|...
Key1=Value13|Key2=Value23|Key3=Value33|...
```

I want to create a data frame like

```
Key1|Key2|Key3
Value11|Value21|Value31
Value12|Value22|Value32
Value13|Value23|Value33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
read.table(text =
    "Key1=Value11|Key2=Value21|Key3=Value31
Key1=Value12|Key2=Value22|Key3=Value32
Key1=Value13|Key2=Value23|Key3=Value33", sep = "|") %>%
    mutate_all(funs(gsub("Key\\d+=", "", .)))
#       V1      V2      V3
#1 Value11 Value21 Value31
#2 Value12 Value22 Value32
#3 Value13 Value23 Value33
```

Explanation:

1. `read.table(..., sep = "|")` reads in your file with `|` as the field separator.
2. `mutate_all(funs(gsub("Key\\d+=", "", .)))` removes the `Key1=`, `Key2=`, `Key3=` parts.

Comment: For completeness, you probably want to set `names(df) <- c("Key1", "Key2", "Key3")`